# Why code "while (true) new Object()" will not cause OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: java, exception

why code

```
while(true)
  new Object();
```

will not cause OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: Because of Garbage Collection. Since the new object is *not strongly reachable* it can be reclaimed (e.g. "deleted") by the GC. Hurrah!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because once each loop iteration is done, the object is eligible for GC (HEAP won't be fill because of this). When JVM needs more memory it can clean up the eligible objects.

I would suggest reading **The Truth About Garbage Collection** (I couldn't post the link here because it has IP, just google it).

Comment: @MaryRyllo: It happens as and when necessary. A little bit of reading on how the JVM works is probably a good idea.

Comment: No, GC won't be called after each object creation (or) each object eligibility for GC. JVM decided when to do GC based on GC algorithms configured.

Comment: @Mary Ryllo - GC is called intdeterminately by the JVM (could be dependent on the JVM) - generally invoked when memory consumption hits certain thresholds.

Answer (score 5):

You are not assigning the new Object to any persistent variable, so you will not run out of memory because the Java Virtual Machine will garbage collect each Object before you have a chance to run out of memory.

On the other hand, if you said

```
List<Object> xs = new LinkedList<Object>();
while (true) {
    xs.add(new Object());
}
```

then they wouldn't get garbage collected automatically and you would eventually run out of memory.

Comment: Note: In C#/.NET this example would *not* hold since the CLR can determine that the list (named by `xs`) is itself not used later. I do not know what the JVM says on this w.r.t local variables *always* being strong reachability roots (or not) ..

Comment: @pst But there's no later to speak of, and as long as the loop is running, xs is actually being used.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ahh, good points. I was forgetting about the [obvious] dependency.

Comment: A nitpick: I'm not sure which `List` class you have in mind -- the usual `java.util.List`, of course, is an interface, such that `xs = new List<Object>();` is a syntax error -- but regardless, it's likely that on a 64-bit JVM with a large enough max-heap-size, this code would actually end up with some sort of "OMG this list is bigger than I can handle!" even before it got to the point of running out of memory. :-P

Comment: @ruakh: "OMG this list is bigger than I can handle!", can you be more specific on this sentence? Curious to know what may happen.

Comment: @Nambari: Well, for example, any sort of list that stores all of its elements in an array will naturally be limited to at *most* 2³¹ elements, since arrays are indexed by signed 32-bit integers. (Oddly, this limitation can still manifest as an `OutOfMemoryError`, but in that case the name is misleading: it can arise even if there is ample room for the entire array.)

Comment: @ruakh On the other hand, no such issue will arise with a `LinkedList`. So it's not exactly regardless :)

Comment: @ruakh: Good point about `new List` not being valid, that was a careless typo, I changed it to LinkedList.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: `LinkedList` is not named `List`. In my experience, most classes named simply `List` do use backing arrays. ("Most", hence my "it's likely that".)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not saving any references to the new objects you create, so the [garbage-collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) can simply remove them whenever it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM guarantees that, no matter what amount of garbage you create, you won't receive an `OutOfMemoryError` if there is reclaimable heap left. The only exception to this would be when the GC performance overhead exceeds a defined threshold. It your case, however, GC-ing is in fact utterly trivial and lightning fast: at each minor collection cycle all the Objects are collected as one huge block in the Thread-Local Area.